# Finding matches in a list property, in a list of class Instances

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I have a class, 'Foo', which has a name (string) and a set of data (a list of integers). I need to be able to find 'test' any string/list combination against a list of Foo's, to find any matches. Like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.data = list(data)


foo1 = Foo('abc', [1, 2, 3])
foo2 = Foo('def', [4, 5, 6])
foo3 = Foo('ghi', [7, 8, 9])

my_list = [foo1, foo2, foo3]

def test(name, data):
    results = []
    for foo in my_list:
        if foo.name == name:
            for number in data:
                if number in foo.data:
                    results.append(number)
    return name, results

print test('def', [2, 3, 4, 5])
```

will return

```
('def', [4, 5])
```

while...

```
print test('gah', [1, 2, 3])
```

will return

```
('gah', [])
```

This basically works, but it looks kind of silly. I was hoping there was a way to use list comprehension or generators to make it prettier. I'm not necessarilly looking to flatten everything to a single one-line expression, as I expect that would be next to impossible to read, but I suspect there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Can there be more than one foo with the same name?

Comment: @JochenRitzel Unsued argument ? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you can restructure a number of things in your code to make it work a bit better.

First, instead of having data be a list, I'd consider a set.  That would allow you to use `data.intersection(otherdata)` to get the overlap.

Next, instead of a list of Foo instances, perhaps a dictionary keyed by their names?  That would let you index into it by your test name, rather than having to loop over the list of instances to find the appropriate one.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.data = set(data)


foo1 = Foo('abc', [1, 2, 3])
foo2 = Foo('def', [4, 5, 6])
foo3 = Foo('ghi', [7, 8, 9])

my_lookup = dict((f.name, f) for f in [foo1, foo2, foo3])

def test(name, data):
    if name in my_lookup:
        return name, my_lookup[name].data.intersection(data)
    return name, []
```

I realized, if you tested for a name you didn't have, you'd get a KeyError, so I adjusted it to handle that appropriately.

Comment: you could make this shorter by writing `if name in my_lookup: return name, my_lookup[name].data.intersection(data)` -- that would make the `return None` superfluous.

Comment: Actually, as I look at the question a bit closer, the OP indicated what would be returned if the test failed, so I went ahead and put that into the answer.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Creating the dictionary **my_lookup** doesn't bring particuliar benefit, I find . Simon Lundberg has _"to loop over the list of instances to find the appropriate one(s)"_ but you do the same to create this dictionary. Letting **my_lookup** outside the function makes also **my_lookup** a free identifier inside the function, which is not the best to do: to test other wanted data, another **my_lookup** will be necessary to be created, then the logic is to introduce it inside the function. But then creation of **my_lookup** inside will be very similar to the one in the code of Simon.

Comment: @agf _"Really, this is the right way to do it."_ I don't think so. My answer speaks for me

Comment: @g.d.d.c I tried to use the ``get()`` method of the dictionary to avoid two lines with ``return`` in your code , but I didn't succeed.

Comment: @eyquem - A dictionary brings benefit in that it prevents you from have to locate the instances every time you test.  Instead, the looping happens once, and instances are then retrievable by name.

Comment: @g.d.d.c You are right. I wonder how I didn't see that before. I modified my answer, and I upvote yours.

Comment: @g.d.d.c But I still think that the position of your dict outside the function isn't a good practice: I agree to the fact that if you triggers several time the function without the number of instances having changed, then your dictionary is still valid. But if new instances are created between uses of the function, the dictionary will need to be first updated. In fact it can't be put inside the function because it should be re-evaluated at each call of the function. I see no other solution than mine: dictionary as class attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could use sets instead of lists:

```
from itertools import chain

def test(name, data):
    data = frozenset(data)
    return name, list(chain.from_iterable(data & set(foo.data)
                                          for foo in my_list
                                          if foo.name == name))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/yaVbi)

Comment: I find this complicated and above all the use of set has the consequence that the order is lost.

Answer (score 0):

*This basically works, but it looks kind of silly.*
Not silly, just inexperimented.

*I was hoping there was a way to use **list comprehension** or **generators** to make it prettier. (...) I **suspect** there's a **better way** of doing this.*
Absolutely, your intuition was good.

A simple way to improve:

```
class Foo:
    dicfoos = {}
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.data = list(data)
        self.__class__.dicfoos.setdefault(self.name,[]).append(self) 

foo1 = Foo('abc', [1, 2, 3])
foo2 = Foo('def', [4, 5, 6])
foo3 = Foo('ghi', [7, 8, 9])
foo4 = Foo('def', [10, 11, 12])

def test(klass,the_name, wanted_data):
    return (the_name,
            tuple( x for foo in klass.dicfoos.get(the_name,())
                   for x in foo.data if x in wanted_data ) )

print test(Foo,'zzz', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
print test(Foo,'def', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
print test(Foo,'abc', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
```

result

```
('zzz', ())
('def', (4, 5, 11))
('abc', (2, 3))
```

A little more sophisticated way of doing:

```
class Foo:
    dicfoos = {}
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.data = list(data)
        self.__class__.dicfoos.setdefault(self.name,[]).append(self)
    def sift(self,daataa):
        for n in self.data:
            if n in daataa:  yield n

foo1 = Foo('abc', [1, 2, 3])
foo2 = Foo('def', [4, 5, 6])
foo3 = Foo('ghi', [7, 8, 9])
foo4 = Foo('def', [10, 11, 12])


def test(klass,the_name,wanted_data):
    return (the_name,
            tuple( x for foo in klass.dicfoos.get(the_name,())
                   for x in foo.sift(wanted_data) ) )

print test(Foo,'zzz', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
print test(Foo,'def', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
print test(Foo,'abc', [2, 3, 4, 5, 11])
```

You can replace the name `tuple` with `list` if it is really necessary, but a tuple is a lighter data structure

### Edit

Taking account of a remark of **g.d.d.c** in a comment I replaced a list **lifoos** with the dictionary **dicfoos**: this latter avoids a lookup when the instances of a precise name are needed, the itel with this precise name gives the list of such instances

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I have restructured my code and it's working much better now. The whole thing is a bit of a cludge, but at the moment that's mostly because I'm working against a piece of software whose Python integration is basically just the ability to send commands via strings.

Much obliged!